# Node server crashing with 'Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, web

I am trying to run a node.js server file, but for some reason it's just started crashing when I try to run it from terminal. I have not made any changes to this file, and none of the changes I have made elsewhere in the system should be affecting it, so I don't understand what's causing this.

This is my terminal output:

```
(base) roland@Rolands-MacBook-Pro webpage % node app

node:fs:456
    return binding.readFileUtf8(path, stringToFlags(options.flag));
                   ^

Error: ETIMEDOUT: connection timed out, read
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:456:20)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1399:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/roland/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Documents/3rd year/Final Project/oo169/webpage/app.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32) {
  errno: -60,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v21.6.1
```

my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



//set the view engine to ejs specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


//middleware to be used by application
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(cookieParser());


//allow additional files to be read
app.use('/styles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles'), { type: 'application/css' }));
app.use('/bootstrap/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js'), { type: 'application/javascript' }));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'scripts'), { type: 'application/javascript' }));


//for sessions
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: oneDay,
    secure: true
  }
}));


//url routes - links to seperate files where specific requests are handled
var indexRoute = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRoute);

var createAccountRoute = require('./routes/createAccount');
app.use('/createAccount', createAccountRoute);

var loginRoute = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', loginRoute);

var filmsRouter = require('./routes/films');
app.use(filmsRouter);


//start server
const port = process.env.PORT
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Started on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: Move the project somewhere else. Don't run it from a cloud storage folder.